# find out many items are there in dictionary in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

A csv file has content as follows
like this it keeps on ever displaying the csv file has columns

> manufacturer    model   displ   year    cyl trans   drv cty hwy fl  class
>   1 audi    a4  1.8 1999    4   auto(l5)    f   18  29  p   compact
>   2 audi    a4  1.8 1999    4   manual(m5)  f   21  29  p   compact

I am writing a program which imports the file csv data as follows.

```
import csv
with open('mpg.csv') as csvfile:
    mpg = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

mpg[:3]
```

the output is following

```
[OrderedDict([('', '1'),
              ('manufacturer', 'audi'),
              ('model', 'a4'),
              ('displ', '1.8'),
              ('year', '1999'),
              ('cyl', '4'),
              ('trans', 'auto(l5)'),
              ('drv', 'f'),
              ('cty', '18'),
              ('hwy', '29'),
              ('fl', 'p'),
              ('class', 'compact')]),
 OrderedDict([('', '2'),
              ('manufacturer', 'audi'),
              ('model', 'a4'),
              ('displ', '1.8'),
              ('year', '1999'),
              ('cyl', '4'),
              ('trans', 'manual(m5)'),
              ('drv', 'f'),
              ('cty', '21'),
              ('hwy', '29'),
              ('fl', 'p'),
              ('class', 'compact')]),
 OrderedDict([('', '3'),
              ('manufacturer', 'audi'),
              ('model', 'a4'),
              ('displ', '2'),
              ('year', '2008'),
              ('cyl', '4'),
              ('trans', 'manual(m6)'),
              ('drv', 'f'),
              ('cty', '20'),
              ('hwy', '31'),
              ('fl', 'p'),
              ('class', 'compact')])]
```

I want to count the number of items in csv file.
If I want to count how many objects are there in each column i.e. individual columns or do some maths on them like finding average etc from prices then how to do so in python. I can easily do that in excel sheet but I am not getting in here how to do.
Trying to find column names with keys

```
import csv
with open('mpg.csv','r') as csvfile:
     reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
     col_name={rows[0]:row[1] for rows in reader}
```

this gives me errors

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-ac3bfb72c9e9> in <module>
      2 with open('mpg.csv','r') as csvfile:
      3      reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
----> 4      col_name={rows[0]:row[1] for rows in reader}

<ipython-input-73-ac3bfb72c9e9> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      2 with open('mpg.csv','r') as csvfile:
      3      reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
----> 4      col_name={rows[0]:row[1] for rows in reader}

NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

then I am trying to do following

- Group the cars by number of cylinder, and finding the average cty
  mpg for each group.
- Find the average cty fuel economy across all
  cars. All values in the dictionaries are strings.
- Find the average hwy fuel economy across all cars

Comment: You can use method len(), in your code "mpg" is a list. So you can use: len(mpg)

Comment: ok how to proceed with following
1. Finding the column names with keys
2.Finding the average city fuel economy across all cars.

Comment: Do you want to do it in pure python or libraries like pandas is fine?

Comment: actually I am learning python so both ways I want to learn I don't have much idea of pandas or basic also. What ever you suggest will improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data in list `mpg`, you can use for example Python `statistics` module to find average ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)):

```
from statistics import mean

print(mean(float(item['cty']) for item in mpg))
```

Note: for average `hwy` fuel change the key `cty` for `hwy`.

---

For finding column names, for example:

```
print(list(mpg[0].keys()))
```

Prints:

```
['', 'manufacturer', 'model', 'displ', 'year', 'cyl', 'trans', 'drv', 'cty', 'hwy', 'fl', 'class']
```

---

Displaying only column `cty`:

```
print([item['cty'] for item in mpg])
```

Prints:

```
['18', '21', '20']
```

More about list comprehensions in [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

---

EDIT: For grouping you can use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)). This will group the cars by number of cylinder, and finding the average cty mpg for each group:

```
from statistics import mean
from itertools import groupby

for v, g in groupby(sorted(mpg, key=lambda k: int(k['cyl'])), lambda k: int(k['cyl'])):
    print('Number of cylinders: {}, average cty mpg: {}'.format(v, mean(float(item['cty']) for item in g)))
```

---

EDIT: Reading from .csv:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open('mpg.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader=list(csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')) # change the delimiter to what is in your csv file
    print (mean(float(item['cty']) for item in reader))  # note the parenthesis around item['cty']: float(item['cty'])
```

Comment: I tried your method to find mean here is my code  
`import csv  
from statistics import mean
with open('mpg.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader=list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
    print (mean(float(item['cty'] for item in reader)))`   I get following error   
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-d92d87f166a4> in <module>
----> 5     print (mean(float(item['cty'] for item in reader)))

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'`

Comment: @ss321c I edited my answer. The problem is that you are missing parenthesis around `item`, it needs to be like this: `float(item['cty'])`.

Comment: Ok I got the mistake your solution is working I am just trying to understand how it is workingI tried another code `import csv
from statistics import mean
with open('mpg.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader=list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

    for item in reader:
        l=[item['cty']]
        new_list=list(map(float,l))
        res=(mean(new_list))
        print (res)` here res I expect to print the mean but instead it prints the list converted to float. Why is this happening any idea.

Comment: @ss321c It's because you're iterating over lines in your csv file and computing average from list containing only one element - and that's always the same float.

Comment: see after for loop I have statement `l=[item['cty']` my understanding is that l should be now a list of strings i.e. l=[18,22,25,40] so mean (l) should work however in original file data is stored as strings so I convert it to float values what I am not understanding is how am I iterating over lines in csv file.

Comment: @ss321c `item` holds only one item, so `item['cty']` holds only one value. The whole list is in the variable `reader`. Try put some `print()` functions around to see what is in your variables.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `pandas` because this is exactly what it's for

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv')

df.describe()  # provides all stats

df.info()  # info about each column
```

- [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)
- [pandas dataframe exploration](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/projects/2019-01-24_pandas_dataframes/2019-01-24_pandas_dataframes.html): go to this notebook and search for `mpg` and you'll find a similar exploration of an automobile dataset.